# В каких случаях необходимо использовать synthesize?

Tags: objective-c

Не могли бы объяснить простыми словами, в каких ситуациях необходим synthesize? Я так понял, он дает возможность обращаться к проперти через get- и set-. Получается, что проперти без synthesize ничем не отличается от переменной класса? И имеет ли тогда вообще смысл писать пропети без synthesize?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Свойства (property) появились в Objective-C только в версии 2.0 и они сводятся к обычным методам (или сообщениям, если угодно). То есть если вы объявляете свойство

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* property1;
```

то на самом деле вы объявляете такие геттер и сеттер:

```
-(NSString*)property1;
-(void)setProperty1:(NSString*)value;
```

Когда вы используете свойство

```
NSString* p = v.property1;
v.property1 = p;
```

на самом деле компилятор «разворачивает» это в такой код:

```
NSString* p = [v property1];
[v setProperty1:p];
```

Оператор `@synthesize property1;` разворачивается в определения кода для сеттера и геттера (в соответствии с параметрами, которые вы указали в объявлении свойства).
Вы можете и не писать `@synthesize`, однако в этом случае вам придется самому написать реализации геттера и сеттера. Если вы не сделаете ни того, ни другого, компилятор выдаст предупреждение, а код, который использует свойство, будет вылетать.

Так как `@property` разворачивается в *объявления* сеттера и геттера, его нужно писать в интерфейсе класса (обычно в файле заголовков - .h). Аналогично, `@synthesize` «генерирует» *реализации* сеттера и геттера, поэтому используется в файле реализации (.m, .mm).

Comment: Вот я не знаю никогда в жизни не видел Objective-C. Я из Вашего ответа так и не понял, в чём разница между @property и @synthesize. По Вашим словам получается, что и то и то «разворачивается в определение кода для сеттера и геттера». Так в чём разница-то?

Comment: Разница в том, что `@property` "раскрывается" в _объявление_ методов, а `@synthesize` - в _определение_ (реализацию) методов. То есть `@property` обычно используется в заголовочных файлах (.h), а `@synthesize` - в файлах реализации (.m, .mm).

Comment: @kirelagin Спасибо за замечание, обновил ответ )

Comment: @y0prst Т.е. правильно ли я понимаю, что если я хочу сам написать пропертю, не тупо присваивающую значение, то я в заголовке использую @property и сами пишу реализацию, а если мне нужна пропертя без специально логики, то объявляю в заголовке через @property, а потом в файле с реализацией использую @synthesize?

Comment: Теперь стало понятно. Да, получается если у нас не обычный сеттер-геттер, а мы хотим выполнить там что-то более замысловатое, то синтесайз не пишем :)

Comment: @kirelagin Да, все именно так. Кроме того, можно, например, написать реализацию одного только сеттера. Встретив @synthesize компилятор посмотрит, есть ли уже геттер и сеттер, и затем реализует те, которых еще нет.

Comment: Ага, я тоже теперь понял :). Надеюсь, мне никогда не придётся с этим встретиться ))).

Answer (score 4):

Из вопроса «[Objective-C is @synthesize required or optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15606151/2553424)»:

> No we don't need to do that as of Xcode 4.4, which added a feature called Default Synthesis Of Properties.
>
> Simply put, it generates this automatically:
>
> ```
> @synthesize name = _name;
> ```

---

Короче, можно не париться: начиная с Xcode 4.4, IDE сама дефолтом устанавливает `@synthesize name = _name;` везде, где это требуется.

Comment: уточнение, если вы определили сетер и гетер сами, то компилятор для такого свойства отключит автосинтез